# Simple time functions in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a tool for my restaurant. Everyday, I have employees input their sales numbers into a Google Form on their phones. The results of which are archived in a Google Sheets spreadsheet as 'FormResults'.

I need a way to auto-write only the most recent values of each employee's formResults data into the appropriate slots to do the daily calculations of tips in sheet1.

I also want to archive the form data. This is why I don't just manually input the data daily into the calculator.

[image: tipCalculator]

This is my crude If statement:

> If {A15=today,B15=Mike} then write Contents of C15 into this cell

A1,B2,C2 are in sheet2 and I want sheet1 to only display the most recent value of each of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do either of these work as you want (assuming cell A1 contains the employee name)?

To return the data from most recent date:

`=MAX(FILTER(sheet2!C:C,sheet2!B:B=A1))`

Or to return data from today

`=FILTER(sheet2!C:C,sheet2!B:B=A1,INT(sheet2!A:A)=TODAY())`